# Link multiple php files to a single stylesheet?

Tags: php, html, css, include

I'm making a simple website with 3 pages in php. The main page is **index.php** and the other two can be opened through **index.php** via links.
The link to CSS is given in the **index.php** file and I want the CSS to get applied to all the other files as well. Do I have to put link tags in all php files to refer to the stylesheet? Is there any other way possible?

Comment: do you have a header.php file then you can add this style file in it it could attach to another files also

Comment: You should put the link in each and every file. index.php (usualy) is the default file that a webserver servers to you when you access a directory without specifying which file you want. For the browser it has no index status, it just loads its output as it would of any other file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had `header/top.php` then copy all those files within your `top.php` as like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>...
```

and you can use top.php within your each php file just by adding

```
<?php include 'pathtocss/top.php'?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have three different pages and linking all the css file in index.php, It will not get reflected in all the pages.

So better you can follow any of the three approach,

1. Put all the css file in one php file, say styles.php and link it in all the pages
2. Separate css file for each page.
3. You can go for [single page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). but you have to do some magics using JS

Now the choice is yours!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do one page named includes.php put into all yours files include and include this page in all your pages